# How to locate the displayRows paragraph between the previous and next page buttons in MUI table pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using a Material-UI table pagination component in my React app and i have to place the paragraph which displays the current range of rows between the two action buttons (previous and next)

```
<TablePagination
      rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
      component="div"
      count={rows}
      page={page}
      onPageChange={handleChangePage}
      rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
      onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
      
      
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way of doing it.

One approach would be to manipulate some of the MUI css classes by giving your `TablePagination` following sx-prop:

```
              sx={{
                "&.MuiTableCell-root .MuiTablePagination-displayedRows": {
                  position: "absolute",
                  right: "50px",
                },
                "&.MuiTableCell-root .MuiTablePagination-actions button:first-of-type":
                  {
                    mr: "100px",
                  },
              }}
```

This will move the first action button to the left and the displayed rows to the right.